# Firefox Vimperator - dark theme makes the command line hard to see. Change using CSS?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, themes, css, vimperator

I'm currently using Vimperator with the [FT Deep Dark theme](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ft-deepdark/) on Firefox 53.0 (32-bit), and the setup is excellent save for one nagging issue - the command line for Vimperator is black text on dark grey background:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK2eC.png)

This doesn't affect the functionality at all, but it's rather annoying that I can barely see what commands I'm typing.

Is there a way to change this by tweaking `userChrome.css` or the Vimperator plugin somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You could use (or adapt/edit) a theme from here:

https://github.com/vimpr/vimperator-colors